# Orthogonal Projection using Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

**Question:**

**U**:=$span((1,1,0))$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Find the Orthogonal Projection $P_U$ of $U$.

**Problem:**

Here, I understand that **U** is only one dimensional. So, every vector in the set would be a multiple of the given vector:
$$n(1,1,0)$$

So, how do I proceed to calculate the orthonormal basis here? I'm very much familiar with the Gram-Schmidt Process but that requires multiple vectors?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Use the formula for projection onto a vector, and expand that into a matrix.

Comment: Hint: Find a basis that contains (1,1,0) and do Gramm-Schmidt on that basis

Comment: @Boxonix That definitely helps! Thank you!